# discord py Как сделать удаление сообщения по реакции в дискорде?

Tags: discord.py

Бот ставит реакцию на сообщение выполнения команды пользователя, если этот пользователь прожмет реакцию то сообщение должно бота должно удалиться

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код взят сверху, он действительно работает, но кое что  в нем не так, а именно метод `add_reactions` следует заменять на `add_reaction`. Также в `@bot. event()` нужно убрать  `()`.

```
@bot.command()
async def delete(ctx):
    global msg
    msg = await ctx.send('Сообщение отправлено!')
    await msg.add_reaction('✅')
    global mmbr, msg_id
    mmbr = ctx.author
    msg_id = msg.id

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.member == mmbr and payload.message_id == msg.id:
        await msg.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, что данный код будет работать. Если не будет, то вашу задумку можно будет реализовать только с помощью базы данных.

```py
@bot.command()
async def delete(ctx):
    global msg
    msg = await ctx.send('Сообщение отправлено!')
    await msg.add_reactions('✅')
    global mmbr, msg_id
    mmbr = ctx.author
    msg_id = msg.id

@bot.event()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.member == mmbr and payload.message_id == msg.id:
        await msg.delete()
```